# Replacing a subset of variables in a polynomial

Tags: replacement

Let's say I have a polynomial in n variables, e.g. x^3 + xyz + z^2, where n=3 in this case. How can I replace all of the variables in the equation with a certain number?

I tried things like

```
eq /. Variables[eq] -> ConstantArray[5,Length[Variables[eq]]]
```

but for some reason that didn't work.

I figure that you somehow need to create a list of rules such as:

```
{ x -> 5, y -> 5, z -> 5 }
```

but I'm not sure how to do that.

Bonus question: how could I replace just some subset of the variables? E.g. I give the input {1,3} and it would replace x and z by 5, but not y.

Comment: You may be looking for `Thread[Variables[eq] -> ConstantArray[...]]`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
eq=x^3 + x*y*z + z^2;
rules=Map[#->5&,Variables[eq]];
eq/.rules

(*which returns 275*)
```

To answer your bonus question I would need to know how you decided it was x and z to replace, but not y.

Answer (score 0):

In continuation to Bills answer, If selective replacement is required, store all the variables first and select the variables based on the input and make the rules.

For example, may not be efficient,

```
eq=x^3 + x*y*z + z^2;
var=Variables[eq];
rules=Table[var[[i]]->5,{i,{1,3}}];
eq/.rules
```